# Convert Java object to JsonNode with change in SerializationConfig per request

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, objectmapper

I am trying to convert a Java Object to JsonNode as follows.

```
mapper.setConfig(mapper.getSerializationConfig().with(contextAttributes));
mapper.valueToTree(object);
```

There is a single objectMapper instance.
So for each request there is a change in objectMapper serialisation config. This is causing concurrency issues since one thread may overwrite the config of mapper set by the previous one. I can't create a new ObjectMapper instance for each request. I can't create even a copy of it as according to ObjectMapper javadoc creating a copy of ObjectMapper is as expensive as creating an new instance.

So what is the best way to convert?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Want to check if there is any other way to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a case for using an [ObjectWriter](https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter.html), which according to its javadoc is

> used for per-serialization configuration of serialization parameters

You create an instance from your `ObjectMapper` and add the specialized configuration like this :

```
ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(contextAttributes);
writer.writeValue(responseOutputStream, object);
```

The `ObjectWriter` class unfortunately doesn't contain an easy way to write the output to a `JsonNode`. If you really need the result to not be a string, you can read it into a tree like this:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
writer.writeValue(sw, object);

JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(sw.toString());
```